# Append every three elements in sublist to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sublist

Say I have a list containing lists.

```
board = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
[8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
[7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
[0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]
```

I want to append every three numbers in each sublist to a key in a dictionary.
For example

```
dd = {1:[5, 3, 0,6, 0, 0,0, 9, 8]}
```

Then I'll look for the next 3x3 section.

```
dd = {2:[0,7,0,1,9,5,0,0,0]}
```

In total I should have 9 keys each with a list of 9 elements.

This clearly doesn't work XD:

```
board = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
[8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
[7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
[0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]
xBx = {}
count1 = 1
count2 = 3
count3 = 0
for row in board:
   if count1 == 4:
       count = 1
   xBx[count1] = row[count3:count2]
   count1 += 1
   count2 += 3
   count3 += 3
   
print(xBx)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using numpy, it's easier to slice a multi-dimensional array

```
import numpy as np

board = np.array(board)
result = {}
for i in range(len(board) // size):
    for j in range(len(board) // size):
        values = board[j * size:(j + 1) * size, i * size:(i + 1) * size]
        result[i * size + j + 1] = values.flatten()
```

And `result` gives

```
{
   1: array([5, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8]), 
   2: array([8, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0]), 
   3: array([0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 
   4: array([0, 7, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0]), 
   5: array([0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0]), 
   6: array([0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 8, 0]), 
   7: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0]), 
   8: array([0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6]), 
   9: array([2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 9])
}
```

Comment: @CodePanda just added the 9 keys version

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are probably looking for

```py
size = 3
l = len(board)

dict = {}
dictIndex = 1

for x in range(0, l, size):
    for y in range(0, l, size):
        a = []
        for i in range(x, x + size):
            for j in range(y, y + size):
                a.append(board[i][j])
        dict[dictIndex] = a
        dictIndex += 1

print(dict)
```

**Shorter variant**

```py
size, l, dict, dictIndex  = 3, len(board), {}, 1
for x in range(0, l, size):
    for y in range(0, l, size):
        dict[dictIndex], dictIndex = [board[i][j] for i in range(x, x + size) for j in range(y, y + size)], dictIndex + 1
print(dict)
```

Comment: advice : When you're using a constant variable multiple times (or even one) store it in a variable, here `3` is repeated all along ;)

Comment: This gives me only 3 sublists.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
board = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
[8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
[7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
[0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]

d = {}

for i in range(len(board[0]) // 3):
    for l in board:
        if i + 1 in d.keys():
            d[i + 1].append(l[0 + i*3])
            d[i + 1].append(l[1 + i*3])
            d[i + 1].append(l[2 + i*3])

        else:
            d[i + 1] = []
            d[i + 1].append(l[0 + i*3])
            d[i + 1].append(l[1 + i*3])
            d[i + 1].append(l[2 + i*3])

for key, value in d.items():
    print(f"{key}     {value}")
```